# Is it possible to run Powershell scripts from test plan?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm new to test plan. I'm trying to run a powershell script from there.

The only way I see it to run the ps script is from outside the testplan as a Job for the agent but that's no use, I want to get results from that execution.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reminder, I forgot to mark it as an answer. Greetings! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A test plan does not support any actions. This is a container for test suites, test cases and test executions. If you want to get test runs, you can use rest api: [Runs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

Comment: thank you for your response :) then why this says that if you want to use this for automation scripts https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops let me check that Runs-List :D thank you!

Comment: @HeberSolis Yes, this is about test executions just automated :). You can try to call powershell script from linked to test case unit test, if this makes sense: [Associate automated tests with test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops), [How to run PowerShell scripts from C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C)

Answer (score 0):

> the only way I see it to run the ps script is from outside the
>   testplan as a Job for the agent but that's no use

As **Shamrai Aleksander** said, test plan is just a container of test suites and test cases. So It's not supported to run PS from test plan itself directly.

I'm not sure why you want to get results in that way using PS script, as I know we can check test results in [web portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops#run-the-automated-tests)(See pic in step5). Also, since we need to configure build and release in Test Plan settings, if you want to run PS script, you can add a Power Shell task before or after the VSTest task in release pipeline.

Comment: Hi Lance! thank you for your response, I think I lacked context in my question, I have automation scripts, which are made from an internal tool, so we use ps scripts to schedule them, and we do that in azure with a ps task job, sometimes we need to run several of them so someone said to make a testplan and put there the ones we need to run, but, from what I've seen, that's not possible, correct? thank you for your help :)

Comment: Since testplan is a container, it's impossible to select several of the ps scripts to run, that's not supported :)